# ng-href doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I have AngularJS v1.3.1 on the project.
I have an anchor tag in my template:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" 
   ng-href="#!/database/{{home.uuidSelectedDatabase}}/segments?{{goToSegmentsUrlQuery}}">
   <i ng-if="!goToSegmentsUrlQuery" 
      class="icon-refresh icon-white pm-icon-spin pm-button-icon"></i>
   <span ng-i18next="segments:set-operations.form.button.go-to-segments"></span>
</a>
```

I expect this anchor to have empty `href` until both `home.uuidSelectedDatabase` and `goToSegmentsUrlQuery` are defined in $scope.

However, Angular doesn't wait until `goToSegmentsUrlQuery` is defined, and for some time I have a link ending with `/segments?`, which is not what I need.

Comment: You need to at least define it in the scope; `$scope.goToSegmentsUrlQuery = ""`, otherwise the object property will be `undefined` and Angular can't watch for changes. This means that when you do define it later on, Angular isn't watching the property because it was initially not defined at all.

Comment: Can you please post your `controller`'s code?

Comment: @Svenskunganka That doesn't help. But I've solved the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by throwing everything out of `ng-href` value except one curly-braced value:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="{{goToSegmentsUrl}}">
...
```

And it worked without pre-defining `$scope.goToSegmentsUrl = ''` in controller.